# Get taxonomy term store in iOS SharePoint client

Tags: ios, taxonomy, sharepoint-api

I couldn't get any lead info on how to retrieve a taxonomy term store using REST API in an iOS  app.

Any information will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

According to [this](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/sharepoint-2013-rest-odata-part-1-readingfetching-information-no-code/) article, *managed taxonomy data cannot be consumed from REST*.

Though, this can be done using [JSOM (sp.taxonomy.js)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj857114(v=office.15).aspx), so it seems reasonable to ask if the same stuff can be ported to iOS or other platforms.

Comment: Please post reason when downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get taxonomy terms by POSTing this SOAP message to `_vti_bin/TaxonomyClientService.asmx`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetKeywordTermsByGuids xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/'>
      <termIds>&lt;id&gt;64d031b6-76bb-49ec-a3b3-cb42b8f0953b&lt;/id&gt;</termIds>
    </GetKeywordTermsByGuids>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you need to include more than one guid in the termIds node, you must post it in an XML format like this:

```
<set>
  <id>guid1</id>
  <id>guid2</id>
  ...
</set>
```

and, of course, HTML escaped.